# How to post array name value which inserted into table?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have uncertain row with three `input` for each `tr`. Maybe 10 rows, maybe 100 rows, it depends on button clicked ( which onclick method is `addDvcPeople()`).

Here is my SQL :

```
$query="insert into IDC (name,id,phone,cloudeid) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

for($i=5;$i<10;$i++)
{   
  $stmt->execute(array($_POST['enName".$i."'],$_POST['enID".$i."'],$_POST['enPhone".$i."'],LAST_INSERT_ID()));
  ......
}
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
function addDvcPeoplef()
{
    newrow = '<tr><td ><input  name="enName'+aDWI+'"></td><td ><input  name="enID'+aDWI+'"></td><td ><input name="enPhone'+aDWI+'"></td></tr>';
    $(newrow).insertAfter($('#staTable tr:eq('+aDWI+')'));
}
```

My sql can not work. I suppose `enName".$i."` is wrong. And `enName"+.$i.+"`,`enName$i` are wrong. Who can help me ?

Comment: What do you really want to do ? Do you want add all the data on the created table into you database ? Or keep adding rows to the exciting HTML table ?

Comment: Is aDWI incremented on each click?

Answer (score 0):

```
$enName=$_POST['enName'.$i];
$enID=$_POST['enID'.$i];
$enPhone=$_POST['enPhone'.$i];

$stmt->execute(array($enName,$enID,$enPhone,LAST_INSERT_ID()));
```

try to use this way..This is working in my case.

Comment: are you sure the `POST` is success ? please try to print the post like `print_r($_POST);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. change this line,

```
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['enName".$i."'],$_POST['enID".$i."'],$_POST['enPhone".$i."'],LAST_INSERT_ID()));
```

To this,

```
$stmt->execute(array($_POST["enName'.$i.'"],$_POST["enID'.$i.'"],$_POST["enPhone'.$i.'"],LAST_INSERT_ID()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send arrays via `$_POST` and `$_GET`. That might make it easier to handle. I would do it like this:

```
function addDvcPeoplef()
{
    newrow = '<tr><td ><input  name="IDC[' + aDWI + '][name]"></td><td ><input  name="IDC[' + aDWI + '][id]"></td><td ><input name="IDC[' + aDWI + '][phone]"></td></tr>';
    $(newrow).insertAfter($('#staTable tr:eq('+aDWI+')'));
}
```

Then you can insert it like this:

```
foreach($_POST['IDC'] as $aDWI => $data)
{
    $stmt->execute(array($data['name'], $data['id'], $data['phone'],   LAST_INSERT_ID()));
    ......
}
```